# Why isn't this Programatically Created Chart Adding to Grid?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, charts, grid

I have created the following chart in XAML, which works fine. Now I know it gives me what I need, I'm now trying to replicate the result programatically so I can add multiple instances to different rows / columns of my grid. I get no errors with my VB, but nothing shows. Is there something simple that I'm missing?

XAML:

```
<ComboBox Name="ComboDate" Grid.Row="1" 
        Background="#333333"
        Foreground="#d1d1d1"
        HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"/>
<chart:RadialGaugeChart Grid.Row="2"
    Palette="{StaticResource CustomColors}"
    VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
    HorizontalAlignment="center"                 
    Style="{StaticResource MinimalChartStyle}"                
    Background="#252526"
    Foreground="#d1d1d1"                
    ChartTitle="CCO KPIs"
    ChartSubTitle="Performance Towards In-Year Targets"
    SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}"
    Name="MyChart"
    FontSize="30">
    <chart:RadialGaugeChart.Series>
        <chart:ChartSeries
            SeriesTitle="Errors"
            DisplayMember="Category"
            ValueMember="Number"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Errors}" />
    </chart:RadialGaugeChart.Series>
</chart:RadialGaugeChart>
```

VB:

```
'Create Grid Rows
Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To 3
    'Create New Row
    GridGauges.RowDefinitions.Add(New RowDefinition)
Next i
'Set User to the First Row
'ScrollTitle.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, 0)

'Create Chart
Dim RadialChart As New De.TorstenMandelkow.MetroChart.RadialGaugeChart
'Set Chart to Row 2
RadialChart.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, 0)
'Set Title
RadialChart.ChartTitle = "Test Title"
'Create Data Class for Radial Chart
Dim ChartDataClass As New TestPageViewModel()
'Set Data Context
RadialChart.DataContext = ChartDataClass

Dim RadialSeries As New De.TorstenMandelkow.MetroChart.ChartSeries

With RadialSeries
    .SeriesTitle = "Error"
    .DisplayMember = "Category"
    .ValueMember = "Number"
    .ItemsSource = ChartDataClass.Errors
End With

'Add Series to Chart
RadialChart.Series.Add(RadialSeries)
```

Comment: You're not adding it to grid anywhere

Comment: Does this not add to grid? RadialChart.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, 0)

Comment: No, that sets the row in which chart has to sit if that happens to be added in grid. To add it you need to call `grid.Children.Add(RadialChart);`

Comment: Perfect. Should I answer my own question for future viewers?

Comment: You're more than welcome to do that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Sriram Sakthivel for providing the answer. I didn't set the Chart as a Child of the Grid.

Solution:

```
grid.Children.Add(RadialChart)
```